# Vitamio library doesn't link ? Could not find method io.vov.vitamio.LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs

Tags: eclipse, libraries, vitamio

i'm trying to use vitamio libs on my project, downloaded the library from 
https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/tree/v3.0
and imported as an eclipse library project.

Then i created a test project which uses the library (Project Properties/ Androd / Add Library), everything seems to be right and the vitamio resources are included in the test project tree, the test activity xml is as follow (grabbed from another StOv post):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:paddingLeft="2px" android:paddingRight="2px"
        android:paddingTop="2px" android:paddingBottom="2px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

        <io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"   android:id="@+id/VideoView">               
        </io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the related code:

```
public class Test extends Activity{

io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView videoView;

private void test_2(){
    String httpLiveUrl = "rtsp://somevideostream";   
    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(httpLiveUrl));
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();
}


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tv);
    if (!io.vov.vitamio.LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs(this)) return;
    test_2();             
}     
}
```

in the test manifest file the vitamio library activity "InitActvity" is correctly entered as follows

```
<activity
        android:name="io.vov.vitamio.activity.InitActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|navigation"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
```

Everything looks fine, the project compiles and build, then when i try to run the code (both on emulator and on an arm7 device) i got:

Could not find method io.vov.vitamio.LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs
and
VFY: unable to resolve static method 312: Lio/vov/vitamio/LibsChecker;.checkVitamioLibs (Landroid/app/Activity;)Z

Failed resolving Lio/vov/vitamio/widget/VideoView$1; interface 126 'Lio/vov/vitamio/MediaPlayer$OnVideoSizeChangedListener;'
The test app show a dialog message saying that it has force closing.

In other words looks like the entire Vitamio libs hasn't built (linked) within the project when building the apk, even if within the eclipse tree eve seems to be ok.

Any idea ?

Tnx in advance to all.

Comment: can you please supply how you set up androidmanifest? thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating Android Library Project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24135842/creating-android-library-project)

Answer (score 4):

**Adding Libraries to Eclipse:**

After Downloading the **VitamioBundle-master** from GitHub,Open the Rootfolder then you are having 2 applications
1)Vitamio
2)Vitamio-Sample

Now Open the eclipse and import the 2 applications

1)Right Click on Vitamio Sample select Properties then Andriod,In the Library
Section Click on Add Button then Select a library Project, in our case (Vitamio App) Finally 
Apply and Click on ok.

2)Finally you get rid of Compile Time Errors.