# Creating Android Library Project

Tags: java, android

I am following a tutorial [here](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/wiki/Getting-Started)
I can't get how to do the "use Vitamio as Android library project" .

How can I use it as an Android library project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create Library Project**
Use following steps

1. File->New->Other
2. Select Android Project
3. Select "Create Project from existing source"
4. Click "Browse..." button and navigate to **Vitamio** in your PC
5. After adding project,Click Finish (Now **Vitamio** project in your workspace)
6. Right-click on your project -> Properties
7. In Android->Library section click Add
8. select recently added project -> Ok

that's it!
Now you can use it as library project.

**Import Above library Project**
To import project,do following steps:

1. In the Package Explorer, right-click your main project and select
   Properties.
2. In the Properties window, select the "Android" properties group at
   left and locate the Library properties at right.
3. Click Add to open the Project Selection dialog.
4. From the list of available library projects, select a project and
   click OK.
5. When the dialog closes, click Apply in the Properties window.
6. Click OK to close the Properties window.
   that's it! enjoy

Comment: @MetaSnarf Happy to help,enjoy coding

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to use external project as library project:

1. Import the project from **File>Import**
2. Select **Existing Android Code Into Workspace**
3. Now in your project goto **Properties > Android**
4. There click Add Button and **select the Vitamio project**

Comment: thanks for this. last one. how can i import this? or am i getting the wrong idea?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to use external project as library project

1. File->New->Other
2. Select Android Project
   3  Select Create Project from existing source
3. Click Browse button and navigate to Vitamio
4. and then Click Finish Button
5. Then right click on Project and select the properties option.
6. Then select the Android option and go to library section.
7. Click on add button and select the recently added project and check the isLibrary checkbox and click on Ok button.
   Now your project become the library project.